# How to use StringDistance class in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, openjpa

I have found a utility class StringDistance in JPA.I wants to know,how to use that class in JPA?
You can get the API [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/openjpa/openjpa/1.0.3/openjpa-1.0.3.jar!/index.html?org/apache/openjpa/lib/util/StringDistance.html).

I wants to know how to use the method `getClosestLevenshteinDistance`?
Any help should be appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

The `StringDistance`  class is **not** a part of [JPA specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/package-summary.html) but a utility class from apache  [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/)  
The class `StringDistance` is helpful in order to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 2):

Levenshtein distance between two strings is the minimum number of changes that need to be applied to the first string in order to get to the second string. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for the  the algorithm details .

The `StringDistance` class has nothing to do  with the JPA specification . It is just an utility class  used by the OpenJPA which is one of the implementation of the JPA specification . Apache Common also provides such [function](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

If OpenJPA found out there is an invalid  configuration property during parsing the openJPA configuration file , it will use the algorithm of Levenshtein distance by calling   `getClosestLevenshteinDistance()` to find out the closest valid property string to this invalid property so that it can provide a suggestion to correct this invalid property.